# Where did the dummy app from Rails engine go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recall when playing around with Rails Engines a while ago, that a `dummy` Rails app was created in the `lib` folder - that app was used to drive the Rails engine for testing purposes. Where did that dummy app go in Rails 3.2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your /test folder by default...

For rspec-rails

`rails plugin new --mountable --dummy-path=spec/dummy`

and change requirement to this in your spec_helper.rb

`require File.expand_path("../../spec/dummy/config/environment", __FILE__)`